# WriteBeyondContentLengthException - websphere 8.5.5.11

Tags: spring, websphere

I have strange exception(WriteBeyondContentLengthException) during adding file to server-response.
the thing is that on tomcat environment everything works(now and before migration) and before migration from spring 2.5.6 to current version for websphere environment also everything was working 
(attached source code didn't change after migration):

```
if (saveAsDialog) {
  contentType = SAVE_AS_DIALOG_CONTENT_TYPE;
  response.setHeader(SAVE_AS_DIALOG_HEADER_NAME, SAVE_AS_DIALOG_HEADER_VALUE + fileName);
}

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "");
response.setHeader("Expires", "");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "");
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(bytes);
outStream.close();
```

websphere 8.5.5.11
used libraries:
4.3.9.RELEASE
ibm java 1.7.1_64

exception stack:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WriteBeyondContentLengthException
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:366)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:234)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:304)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:308)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:154)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:288)
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:119)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at com.XXX.YYY.web.spring.ZZZDispatcherServlet.doService(ZZZDispatcherServlet.java:25)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.XXX.YYY.web.core.filters.BrowserCacheFilter.doFilter(BrowserCacheFilter.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.XXX.YYY.web.core.filters.ZZZZZ5Filter.doFilter(ClickJackingFilter.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.XXX.YYY.web.core.filters.ZZZZZ4Filter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:48)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.XXX.YYY.web.core.filters.ZZZZZ3Filter.doFilter(CryptoFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: Please add your full controller method. Looks like you are using an `@RestController` (or `@ResonseBody` ) on a controller returning a `String` but you are already writing the content yourself.

Comment: thanks, you are right, it was caused by annotation @ResponsBody on controller method. 
I can not accept your comment as a solution, if you create separate answer I will accept it.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning anything from the method, it should be a `void` method without any `@ResponseBody` annotation. You are writing the response yourself inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you are writing the response yourself, including setting the headers.

Judging from the error you get you are also returning something from the controller and have either an `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody` annotation on the method.

However as you are writing the response yourself, the method should return `void` and not include an `@ResponseBody` annotation.